# Angular advanced searchbox lose focus after selecting suggested key-value per keyboard

Tags: angularjs

I've implemented the angular-advanced-searchbox (with AngularJS 1.5.8, ui-bootstrap, JQuery) like the demo-page:

**html**

```
<nit-advanced-searchbox ng-model="searchParams" parameters="availableSearchParams" placeholder="Search..."></nit-advanced-searchbox>
```

**script**

```
$scope.availableSearchParams = [
      {...},
      { 
        key: "city", 
        name: "City", 
        placeholder: "City...", 
        restrictToSuggestedValues: true, 
        suggestedValues: ['Berlin', 'London', 'Paris'] },
      {...}
    ];
```

};

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/n6AD13?p=info) is a Plunker of this implementation too. I'll refer to this example to picture my problem.

If I type 'city' in the searchfield and select it by hitting enter, then I'll see the suggested Value-List (Berlin, London, Paris) for about a second and then the focus 'll lost and the selected key-value (city) is automatically removed. It seems this won't happen, if the mouse pointer is rested over the search-input field (without any action).

With this issue, I can't use this module on my site - but I really want to :) Are any suggestions out there?

Answer (score 0):

OK, this (low-level) fix worked for me - i've just commented line 107 ():

**angular-advanced-searchbox-tpls.js [#107]**

```
$scope.searchQueryChanged = function (query) {
    // updateModel('change', 'query', 0, query);
};
```

This line is used to build 'pre-queries'. If you start typing 'city', the scope of searchParams generate a temporary query on the fly and would be changed to the selected key - g.E.:

```
{"query":"ci"}
```

This will then lead to a timeout after 'city' is selected. I don't know this 'query' is used for - all things 'll do their job furthermore. But by time I'll looking to a real fix for this problem :)